# Bash search for IP in table

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am having trouble with a simple search of an output of values in a table. This is the output from my nova command:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| Ip         | Server Id | Fixed Ip | Pool     |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 10.10.10.1 |           | -        | floating |
| 10.10.10.2 |           | -        | floating |
| 10.10.10.3 |           | -        | floating |
| 10.10.10.4 |           | -        | floating |
| 10.10.10.5 |           | -        | floating |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Lets say I am looking for 10.10.10.4. I need to run this nova command to output this table, then search the table for 10.10.10.4. For each IP that is NOT 10.10.10.4 I need to run:

```
nova floating-ip-delete <ip>
```

command. Once it finally finds the correct IP, the script stops.

In essence, we are capturing a large block of floating IPs at a time (5 in this table/example), looking to see if we captured a specific IP, and if not, releasing the IPs back to the pool. Then rinse and repeat until we finally catch the right IP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*** UPDATE ***

Here is where I am at so far. Please ignore the first parts with the tenantid section. This is just some internal checks for safety:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Capture floating IP

################# CONFIG ##################
FLOAT="blah"
TENANTID="blah"
###########################################

# Start
if ! [ "$TENANTID" = "$OS_TENANT_ID" ]; then
        echo "ERROR"
else
        for ((i=1;i<=10;i++));
        do
                echo $i
                nova floating-ip-create floating
        done
        nova floating-ip-list > BLOCK
        while read garbage1 IP garbage2;
        do
                if [ "$IP" != "FLOAT" ]; then
                        nova floating-ip-delete "$IP"
                else
                        exit 0
                fi
        done < <(tail -n +4 /tmp/BLOCK)
fi
```

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: what about `10.10.10.5` ? Leave that or delete it? Good luck.

Comment: Good point, all IPs not matching need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
while read garbage1 ip garbage2; do
    if [ "$ip" != '10.10.10.4' ]; then
        nova floating-ip-delete "$ip"
    else
        exit 0
    fi
done < <(tail -n +4 /path/to/file | head -n -1)
```

Read about:

[Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), [Read builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins), [tail(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail), [head(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head)

Comment: Could you elaborate on garbage1 ip garbage2 please. It looks like I need to output the table to a file which you are then reading into the while loop, but I'm not seeing it completely.

Comment: Yep, this script assumes that the table is stored in the `/path/to/file`. If you want to read it from the stdin, just remove the `/path/to/file`.

Comment: So can you explain the first line a bit more please. In particular the garbage2?

Comment: @Atomiklan What `read` builtin does is reading one line from the input file. It can assign what it has just read to variables, in this case, `garbage1`, `ip` and `garbage2`. The variables will have values of words in the input line. Words are separated by whitespace. The last variable is assigned the rest of the line. For example, `read` command will split the first line so that `garbage1 == "|"`, `ip == "10.10.10.1"` and `garbage2 == "|           | -        | floating |"`.

Comment: Added an update above where I am at currently. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Last thing I probably need to figure out is how to finish the loop even if the correct IP is located. ie, we need to make sure all the unused floating IPs are returned back to the pool. Let me look over my code again now that I understand more of whats going on.

Comment: Looks like everything is working with the exception of it tried to read the last line of the file. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: Thank you very much! This got me exactly where we needed to go!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $(novaCommand | grep '10.10.10.4') = "" ]] ; do
  for i in $(novaCommand | grep -Eo '10\.10\..*') ; do 
   nova floating-ip delete ${i}
  done
done
exit
```

Comment: Those IPs are just for examples. No need to get caught up on them. The IP in reality will be a public address and stored to a variable. For example float="enter public ip here"

Comment: `grep -Eo '.*\..*\..*\..*'` and `grep -Eo 'Same thing or whatever IP you want'`

Comment: First grep will search for any IP (use this in the for statement) OR you can search for specific IP (use this in while statement to see if the IP you are looking for is there... Example being `grep "${floatIP}`).